# A non-numeric value encountered Laravel5.5 on Migration

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-artisan, artisan-migrate

I am getting this error `[ErrorException] A non-numeric value encountered` when I give an artisan command `php artisan migrate:fresh --seed`.

This issue arised when I upgraded to php 7.1 in xammp.

When I am not seeding the error does not occur.

Below is the model factory

```html
$factory->define(App\Clients::class, function (Faker $faker) {
    return [
        'firstname' => $faker->firstName($gender = null|'male'|'female'),
        'lastname' => $faker->lastName($gender = null|'male'|'female'),
        'email' => $faker->unique()->safeEmail,
        'phone' => $faker->e164PhoneNumber(),
        'country' => $faker->country(),
        'university' => $faker->city()
    ];
});
```

Is there a workaround on this issue?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is the code?

Comment: I have eddited my question

Comment: It's a new notice/warning in 7.1 when strings are coerced using operators expecting numbers or their assignment equivalents.

Comment: What can I do to make it work?

Comment: You have to find the code that is trying to use arithmetic on a non-number. It doesn't give a file and line number?

Comment: Thank you for your help. I have resolved the issue

Comment: If you solved it, update this thread with your solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the cause of the error:
        'firstname' => $faker->firstName($gender = null|'male'|'female'),
        'lastname' => $faker->lastName($gender = null|'male'|'female'),

You can just use:
        'firstname' => $faker->firstName(),
        'lastname' => $faker->lastName(),

So that it won't return that error mention above by AbraCadaver